# How to make a Keras Neural Net output values?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am wondering how I can make a Keras layer output a number, and not a set label.
In my code, I am having a neural net learn the Pythagorean theorem. I need it to output a **not set** number as an answer. Can you help?

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras


data = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 7], [9, 10], [3, 6], [10, 15]])
labels = np.array([5,25,74,181,45,325])
print(data[0].size)

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tensorflow.nn.relu, input_shape=[data[0].size])])
```

Comment: I think you are asking how to have continuous output instead of an integer output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your net output has size `(batch_size,8)`. If you want to output a single number you need to add a new layer with outuput size 1, `keras.layers.Dense(1)`. The activation is up to you but as you want a positive number, relu would be probably right.

Comment: So I just make the layer have 1 output?

Comment: I mean, add a new one, don't replace the current or maybe your net won't be able to learn anything. Actually you can add any number of layers as you want, just make sure the final outputs one.